# Insert with sed n repeated characters

Tags: bash, sed

Creating a printout file from a mysql query, I insert a separation line after every TOTAL string with:

```
sed -i /^TOTAL/i'-------------------------------------------------- ' file.txt
```

Is there any more elegante way to repeat n "-" characters instead of typing them?

For instance, if I had to simply generate a line without finding/inserting, I would use:

```
echo -$-{1..50} | tr -d ' '
```

but don't know how to do something similar with sed into a file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just combine the two:

```
sed -i /^TOTAL/i"$(echo -$___{1..50} | tr -d ' ')" file.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happens here with `echo -$___{1..50}` ? What is `$___` ?

Comment: @sputnick Sorry: Changed "-$___{1..50}" into "-$-{1..50}" as ___ whas a copy/paste mistake from the original.

Comment: `-$-{1..50}` doesn't works (`echo -$_{1..50}` does) and that don't explain anything

Comment: @sputnick I know, just tried to explain why I changed ___ to - in the original post, as writen in the edit notes.

Comment: The strange way of producing dashes works because `-$foo{1..3}` brace expands to `-$foo1 -$foo2 -$foo3`, which (since `$foo1` isn't a set variable) expands to `- - -`. In this case, `foo` just happens to be the equally valid variable prefix `___`.

Answer (score 3):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), you can repeat a character N times, see :

```
perl -pe 's/^TOTAL.*/"-"x50 . "\n$&"/e' file.txt
```

or :

```
perl -pe 's/^TOTAL.*/sprintf("%s\n%s", "-"x50, $&)/e' file.txt
```

and you keep a syntax close to `sed`.

Comment: There *had* to be a perl one-liner in the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Another way using builtin `printf` and bash *brace expansion* :

```
sed -i "/^TOTAL/i $(printf '%.0s-' {0..50})" file.txt
```