# sed: Repeat pattern in replace section

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I want to replace a normal PATERN1 by a repeating pattern (PATERN2), in my case repeating 'N' 500 times.

Is it possible to do it simply with sed?

> sed 's/PATERN1/N{500times}/g'

Cheers,

Ricardo

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072875/insert-with-sed-n-repeated-characters

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't found that before! 
I don't understand if it's possible with sed, but there is a similar solution there with perl: perl -pe 's/PATERN1/"N"x500 . ""/e'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` you can do this:

```
s="foo abc PATTERN foo bar PATTERN"

sed "s/PATT[^[:blank:]]*/$(printf '%.0bN' {1..10})/g" <<< "$s"
```

```
foo abc NNNNNNNNNN foo bar NNNNNNNNNN
```

Here `printf '%.0bN' {1..10}` will return a string of `N` repeated 10 times.

Comment: This is just a copy/paste of one of the solution provided by @GillesQuenot on the "original" question.

Comment: Just for reference I learnt `printf` trick from [this 7+ years old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349842/548225)